# use custom helper in controller cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp, model-view-controller, cakephp-3.0

I am using `cakephp v3` and want to ask how to use `custom helper` in `controller`

I have tried below code.

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Cake\Core\Configure;
use Cake\Network\Exception\NotFoundException;
use Cake\View\Exception\MissingTemplateException;
use App\Controller\AppController;
use Cake\Event\Event;
use Cake\Network\Request;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
use Cake\Auth\DefaultPasswordHasher;
use Cake\View\View;
use Cake\View\Helper\HtmlHelper;
use Cake\View\Helper\UrlHelper;
use Cake\View\Helper;
use App\View\Helper\SecurityHelper;

/**
 * Static content controller
 *
 * This controller will render views from Template/Pages/
 *
 * @link http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/pages-controller.html
 */
class PagesController extends AppController {
 function beforeFilter(Event $event) {
        parent::beforeFilter($event);

        $this->viewBuilder()->helpers(['Security']);
}

 public function receiveSaving() {
        pr(($this->request->params['id'])); //die;
        pr($this->Security->decrypt('7JCdO3vIqAU_EQUALS_')); die;
        $this->viewBuilder()->layout('front');
        $this->set('title', '');
        $this->set('meta_title', '');
        $this->set('meta_description', '');
        $this->set('meta_keywords', '');
        //$this->render('savings_bond_result');
    }
```

and getting below error.

> Error: Call to a member function decrypt() on boolean File
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\src\Controller\PagesController.php Line: 204

I tried with some other methods like

```
$Security = new SecurityHelper(new \Cake\View\View());
pr($Security->decrypt('7JCdO3vIqAU_EQUALS_')); die;
```

> Error: Class 'App\Controller\SecurityHelper' not found File
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\src\Controller\PagesController.php Line: 204

Comment: ...and what happened?

Comment: check the updated question.

Comment: Helpers are for views, you **do not** use them anywhere else!

Comment: The answer is don't! Helpers are for views only as @ndm stated. As it's a custom helper you probably want to look at re-writing your code so that the method is available from within your controller as well as the helper.

Comment: If you *only* need your custom functionality in your controllers and not in your views, then a component would be the way to go.

Comment: If you need methods to use in controllers and views, use a Lib. Just a normal php class.

Comment: Yes, I know this is wrong way. and I have fix. Anyway want to know is there any method for do so?

Answer (score 1):

```
$customdtfhelper = new \App\View\Helper\CustomDtfHelper(new \Cake\View\View());
$customdtfhelper->method_name();
```